# can't find a way to list email replies

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

I am working on integration with Microsoft Graph and can't find a way to list all replies for specific email so the user can respond to it

we have implemented this idea on Gmail API through the thread concept 
but in Microsoft Graph we found that the thread word has different use

I have found something in common between the original mail and its replies which is `conversationId` but it's impossible to get and filter all sent messages and also received ones to just find the mails have the same `conversationId`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure where you got the idea that you can't filter on `conversationId` but it absolutely can be. The following will return any messages matching the conversation:

```
/v1.0/me/messages?$filter=conversationId eq '{conversationId}'
/v1.0/users/{id|userPrincipalName}/messages?$filter=conversationId eq '{conversationId}'
```

Comment: will get the replies of the two sides of the conversation?  another thing outside this issue , can i get the mail id after sending it in the response with 202 accepted?

Comment: Yes, it should retrieve all of the messages with that `conversationId` from the mailbox regardless of the folder its in. I'm not sure what you mean by getting the mail id after sending.

Comment: i want to save the message id that i have just sent, so i can let the user reply or see all replies on it, what i wanted is to get the mail id, it has just saved with on microsoft servers

Comment: The `id` of a message is mutable so it should not be stored. You should take a look at the new [immutable id](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-immutable-id) that is preview.

Comment: Thanks a lot for you help, i appreciate that